# Display resolution

Tags: display, screen-resolution

How can I increase the display device resolution in the screenshot from 800 x 600 to 1920 x 1080? I am using the windows server 2019 datacenter VM. It changes to 1920 until I log on. The display screenshot resolution of the same VM I created a few months ago was in 1920

[enable instance virtual display](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-instance-virtual-display)

[screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNwpd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing the display driver "Google Graphics Array (GGA) Properties" to "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter". Google updated the driver version from 2019 to 2022 version, the new one shows 800x600 resolution.

*Thanks for the -2 encouraging me the find the answer by myself and know that google cloud won't help me unless I paid for the highest plan.*

Comment: You didn't even mention Google Cloud in your question.

Comment: By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions can attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or missing details.